# Unbound error using python's unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing

I would like a seperate class to run all of my tests, and then call that class from main to display the results.  Unfortunately, I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dhatt/workspace/pyqt_DALA_ServiceTracker/src/Main.py", line 21, in <module>
    allsuite = unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(TestAllSuite)
TypeError: unbound method loadTestsFromModule() must be called with TestLoader instance as first argument (got type instance instead)
```

How do I change my code so that I can run my tests?

I am using python 2.6.5.

If you find that my testing structure itself also poses a problem (where main calls the main testing class that then calls all my other testing classes), let me know.  I am open to suggestions to a better layout of my testing code (the examples off of the internet only give you the very basics when using unittest)

Here is my code from TestAllClass (it is calling other test classes)

```
import unittest
from TestSettings import TestSettings
from TestConnectDB import TestConnectDB


class TestAllSuite(unittest.TestCase):

    def testsuite(self):
        suite_settings = TestSettings.suite()
        suite_connectDB = TestConnectDB.suite()
        alltests = unittest.TestSuite([suite_settings, suite_connectDB])
        return alltests
```

and here is part of my main that calls TestAllClass

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    allsuite = unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(TestAllSuite)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(allsuite)
```

Here is an example of one of my test classes (if that helps):

```
from Settings import Settings
import unittest


class TestSettings(unittest.TestCase):
    def suite(self):
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        tests = ['test_confirm_ip', 'test_valid_conn','test_correct_location']
        return unittest.TestSuite(map(suite, tests))

    def setUp(self):
        self._test_settings = Settings('/home/dhatt/ServiceTrackerSettings.ini')
        self.ip_add, self.conn, self.digby =    self._test_settings._get_config_variables()

    def tearDown(self):
        self._test_settings = None
        self.ip_add = None
        self.conn = None
        self.digby = None

    def test_confirm_ip(self):
        self.assertEqual((str(self.ip_add)), ('142.176.195.250'))

    def test _confirm_conn(self):
        self.assertEqual((str(self.conn)), ('conn1'))

    def test_confirm_location(self):
        self.assertEqual((self.digby), (True))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `loadTestsFromModule` (in your case `TestAllSuite`), should be a module, not a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`:

```
allsuite = unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(TestAllSuite)
```

For example, here is a little script which runs all unit tests found in files of the form `test_*.py`:

```
import unittest
import sys
import os

__usage__='''
%prog      # Searches CWD
%prog DIR   
'''

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        unit_dir=sys.argv[1]
    else:
        unit_dir='.'
    test_modules=[filename.replace('.py','') for filename in os.listdir(unit_dir)
                  if filename.endswith('.py') and filename.startswith('test_')]
    map(__import__,test_modules)

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for mod in [sys.modules[modname] for modname in test_modules]:
        suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(mod))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the clarification.  And thanks for the script, I never thought of looking it that way.  I'll see how it performs later on with more tests added, but it looks good so far.

Comment: Also, if I had the 2.7 version of python, I could just do this.
http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover
Pity...

Comment: @Danny: Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of `TestLoader.discover`.

Comment: @unutbu thanks for the post it was very helpful! I do have a question though. if i want to run different files in a particular order, how would i specify that?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: The modules (files) containing unit tests will be run in the order in which they are added to `suite`. I'm not sure if this is documented behavior, but it is the current behavior due to [this line](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04d3d67ef5ac/Lib/unittest/suite.py#l110), and because `__iter__` [loops through `self._tests`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04d3d67ef5ac/Lib/unittest/suite.py#l37) and [`addTest` appends to `self._tests`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04d3d67ef5ac/Lib/unittest/suite.py#l55).

Comment: @unutbu ok so if it goes in order... lets say for instance i have a `test_register.py` and a `test_login.py`.. how would I run the register before login? do I need to make a new list and append `test_modules` in the order I want to it?

Comment: Do you know the names of all the files you wish to run?

Comment: Yes I will.. there will be about 7 files

Comment: Then define `test_modules = ['test_register', 'test_login', ...]`, instead of the `test_modules=[filename.replace('.py','') ...]` that I use above.

Comment: Oh duh... well thats simple! I was looking at it completely differently... Thanks for the quick response, very helpful.. im gunna give you a few +1 's :)

Comment: Btw, the system has a way of recognizing (and removing) serial upvoting, but thank you for the sentiment anyway :)